# How to run dotnet new from powershell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I have installed dotnet-sdk-7.0.101-win-x86.exe by downloading it and running it.  This is verified by the fact that if I try to run it again it goes to a different screen where I can modify it.

I am attempting to follow the instructions for a course on Udemy on creating a console app, however I am purposely doing something different.  In the course the instructor is explaining to set everything up under his user directory (in windows).  I would like not to do that.

The reason I don't want to do that Is I have a folder already that has my work stuff in it and I want this to work for my work stuff also.  For me, this folder is C:\SourceCode\ (something).  I have a folder called GitHub that has all the repositories I've downloaded for work and I have another folder called 'Local' which I am using for learning.  So, this is the output I try to create a new HelloWorld console app:

```
PS C:\SourceCode\Local\dotnet-course-code> dotnet new -n HelloWorld
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'new' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
PS C:\SourceCode\Local\dotnet-course-code>
```

I did some googling already to try to solve the problem, One insightful post had me run the following command which I believe proves that the dotnet thing was installed (but I could be wrong)

```
PS C:\SourceCode\Local\dotnet-course-code> Get-Command dotnet |Format-List


Name            : dotnet.exe
CommandType     : Application
Definition      : C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
Extension       : .exe
Path            : C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
FileVersionInfo : File:             C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
                  InternalName:     .NET Host
                  OriginalFilename: .NET Host
                  FileVersion:      6,0,922,41905 @Commit: 163a63591cf9e9b682063cf3995948c2b885a042
                  FileDescription:  .NET Host
                  Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
                  ProductVersion:   6.0.9 @Commit: 163a63591cf9e9b682063cf3995948c2b885a042
                  Debug:            False
                  Patched:          False
                  PreRelease:       False
                  PrivateBuild:     False
                  SpecialBuild:     False
                  Language:         English (United States)
```

I would like to know why this doesn't work as expected.  Note this is on a brand new machine running windows 11 and these commands are being run in powershell.

Comment: Hmmm seems like you need to say what kind of new project.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the crucial part of the error message:

```bash
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.
```

In order to create source-code *projects*, you need to download the [.NET *SDK*](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0), specifically.

The presence of `dotnet.exe` alone does *not* imply that an *SDK* installed, given that it is possible to install a *runtime* only.

If you run `dotnet --info`, you'll see what SDKs and runtimes are installed.

If no SDK is listed, you'll have to install one.

*Update*: As you note, the problem was that you had accidentally created *parallel* installations (a x86 version alongside an x64 one), and the one you tried to use lacked an SDK.

---

Once one is installed, your command should work *if* you also specify a project *type*, [which is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new), as [topsail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467914/topsail) points out; e.g., to create a *console* application in subfolder `HelloWorld`:

```bash
# OK, once an SDK is installed.
dotnet new console -n HelloWorld
```

Comment: I see, yes running the command you suggested above revealed that no SDK was installed. I see also the actual problem was that I had downloaded and installed the x86 version of the SDK earlier when in fact what I needed was the x64 version is what was needed.

Comment: I see, @DallasCaley, thanks for the feedback - I've added a note to that effect to the answer.